# How can I filter populated values in sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, join, sails.js, waterline

I have model `User`. To simplify my issue it has not attributes (except id that is produced by sails engine):

```
module.exports = {

}
```

I have also model `UserPost`:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        user: {
            required: true,
            model: 'user'
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find posts of user with id equal to 42. I have that records in database, both user with id 42, and its posts.

This doesn't work:

```
UserPost.find().populate('user', {
    id: 42
}).exec(function(err, posts) {
    res.json(posts);
});
```

Of course, in this case I can just pass query criteria to `find()`. Anyway in general I should be able to find not only by id but the other attributes too.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the problem was my wrong understanding of what population criteria is. The solution is

- create one-to-many association for `User` and `UserPost` models
- find user and populate it to his post. Something like:

```
User.findOne({
    id: 42
}).populate('userPosts').exec(function(err, user) {
    res.json(user.userPosts);
});
```

This works well.

Comment: @zieglar. Because I want to be able to find not only by id. I mention it in the end of the question. With this approach, I can find for example posts of user by giver username or posts of users that was registered last month and so on. Not my downvotes, by the way.